# Login Authentication doesn't work first time

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am working on Login Activity in Android app. I am using template from Android Studio but with little modification.

When I am trying to sign in first time I have an error "Incorrect Password" but when I am trying sign in second time with same data everything works fine.

I think problem is here

```
public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        private final String mEmail;
        private final String mPassword;

        UserLoginTask(String email, String password) {
            mEmail = email;
            mPassword = password;
        }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                Call<User> call = apiService.DataForUser(mEmail);
                call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                        user=response.body();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return false;
            }

            if(user!=null)
            {
                String hash_pass = Hashing.sha256()
                        .hashString(mPassword, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                        .toString();

                if(hash_pass.equals(user.getPassword())) {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
            mAuthTask = null;
            showProgress(false);

            if (success) {
                Switch();
            } else {
                mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
                mPasswordView.requestFocus();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            mAuthTask = null;
            showProgress(false);
        }
    }
```

All code from the Activity class:

```
    public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    /**
     * Id to identity READ_CONTACTS permission request.
     */
    private static final int REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 0;

    /**
     * Keep track of the login task to ensure we can cancel it if requested.
     */
    private UserLoginTask mAuthTask = null;

    // UI references.
    private AutoCompleteTextView mEmailView;
    private EditText mPasswordView;
    private View mProgressView;
    private View mLoginFormView;

    //Retrofit
    private Api api;
    private ApiService apiService;

    //User
    User user = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        // Set up the login form.
        mEmailView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
        populateAutoComplete();

        mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        mPasswordView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (id == R.id.login || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                    attemptLogin();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        Button mEmailSignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button);
        mEmailSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                attemptLogin();
            }
        });

        mLoginFormView = findViewById(R.id.login_form);
        mProgressView = findViewById(R.id.login_progress);

        //Retrofit
        api = Api.getInstance();
        apiService = api.getApiService();
    }

    private void populateAutoComplete() {
        if (!mayRequestContacts()) {
            return;
        }

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    private boolean mayRequestContacts() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            return true;
        }
        if (checkSelfPermission(READ_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        }
        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(READ_CONTACTS)) {
            Snackbar.make(mEmailView, R.string.permission_rationale, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                    .setAction(android.R.string.ok, new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_CONTACTS}, REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Callback received when a permissions request has been completed.
     */
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS) {
            if (grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                populateAutoComplete();
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Attempts to sign in or register the account specified by the login form.
     * If there are form errors (invalid email, missing fields, etc.), the
     * errors are presented and no actual login attempt is made.
     */
    private void attemptLogin() {
        if (mAuthTask != null) {
            return;
        }

        // Reset errors.
        mEmailView.setError(null);
        mPasswordView.setError(null);

        // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
        String email = mEmailView.getText().toString();
        String password = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

        boolean cancel = false;
        View focusView = null;

        // Check for a valid password, if the user entered one.
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(password) && !isPasswordValid(password)) {
            mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_password));
            focusView = mPasswordView;
            cancel = true;
        }

        // Check for a valid email address.
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
            focusView = mEmailView;
            cancel = true;
        } else if (!isEmailValid(email)) {
            mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email));
            focusView = mEmailView;
            cancel = true;
        }

        if (cancel) {
            // There was an error; don't attempt login and focus the first
            // form field with an error.
            focusView.requestFocus();
        } else {
            // Show a progress spinner, and kick off a background task to
            // perform the user login attempt.
            showProgress(true);
            mAuthTask = new UserLoginTask(email, password);
            mAuthTask.execute((Void) null);
        }
    }

    private boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
        //TODO: Replace this with your own logic
        return email.contains("@");
    }

    private boolean isPasswordValid(String password) {
        //TODO: Replace this with your own logic
        return password.length() > 4;
    }

    /**
     * Shows the progress UI and hides the login form.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
    private void showProgress(final boolean show) {
        // On Honeycomb MR2 we have the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs, which allow
        // for very easy animations. If available, use these APIs to fade-in
        // the progress spinner.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
            int shortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

            mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            mLoginFormView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                    show ? 0 : 1).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });

            mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            mProgressView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                    show ? 1 : 0).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
                }
            });
        } else {
            // The ViewPropertyAnimator APIs are not available, so simply show
            // and hide the relevant UI components.
            mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        return new CursorLoader(this,
                // Retrieve data rows for the device user's 'profile' contact.
                Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI,
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY), ProfileQuery.PROJECTION,

                // Select only email addresses.
                ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE +
                        " = ?", new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email
                .CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE},

                // Show primary email addresses first. Note that there won't be
                // a primary email address if the user hasn't specified one.
                ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.IS_PRIMARY + " DESC");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
        List<String> emails = new ArrayList<>();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            emails.add(cursor.getString(ProfileQuery.ADDRESS));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        addEmailsToAutoComplete(emails);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader) {

    }

    private void addEmailsToAutoComplete(List<String> emailAddressCollection) {
        //Create adapter to tell the AutoCompleteTextView what to show in its dropdown list.
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<>(LoginActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, emailAddressCollection);

        mEmailView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    private interface ProfileQuery {
        String[] PROJECTION = {
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.IS_PRIMARY,
        };

        int ADDRESS = 0;
        int IS_PRIMARY = 1;
    }

    /**
     * Represents an asynchronous login/registration task used to authenticate
     * the user.
     */
    public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        private final String mEmail;
        private final String mPassword;

        UserLoginTask(String email, String password) {
            mEmail = email;
            mPassword = password;
        }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                Call<User> call = apiService.DataForUser(mEmail);
                call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                        user=response.body();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return false;
            }

            if(user!=null)
            {
                String hash_pass = Hashing.sha256()
                        .hashString(mPassword, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                        .toString();

                if(hash_pass.equals(user.getPassword())) {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
            mAuthTask = null;
            showProgress(false);

            if (success) {
                Switch();
            } else {
                mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
                mPasswordView.requestFocus();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            mAuthTask = null;
            showProgress(false);
        }
    }

    public void Switch (){
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Succes!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity (intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: this isn't an Android Studio issue, don't use that tag. And add **the full code into the question**. There are people who can't view Pastebin, and links end up breaking.

Comment: so you're downloading the correct user password and matching it to the tried password on your device? This is extremely dangerous... Also the authentication must be done in the onResponse call

Comment: A lot of questions about your question but most importants are:

1) Why do you use Retrofit implementation inside an Async Task?(Retrofit calls are already implemented on background thread)
2) Why are you downloading the user's data and doing authentication on the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the fact that it seems that you're trying to do the password match on your client, which is **always wrong and dangerous** if you want to match the data that you retrieve from your API call you must include your authentication logic inside the callback function **onResponse**. In your activity, instaed of this:

```
    } else {
        // Show a progress spinner, and kick off a background task to
        // perform the user login attempt.
        showProgress(true);
        mAuthTask = new UserLoginTask(email, password);
        mAuthTask.execute((Void) null);
    }
```

do this because you do not need another async task since Call is already asynchronous ( see @matrix comments):

```
} else {
    // Show a progress spinner, and kick off a background task to
    // perform the user login attempt.
    showProgress(true);
    Call<User> call = apiService.DataForUser(email);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
        user=response.body();
        if(user!=null){
          String hash_pass = Hashing.sha256()
          .hashString(password, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
          .toString();

          if(hash_pass.equals(user.getPassword())) {
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }
}
```

Please adapt your boolean returns considering this new configuration and please if this is a login form logic don't do the password matching in your client but do this on your server and then pass to the client a token or something else.

> > When I am trying to sign in first time I have an error "Incorrect Password" but when I am trying sign in second time with same data everything works fine.

This is because the first time the callback is not ready and then `user` is `null`, the second time user is already ready from the previous call and the logic works

Comment: move the `Call` outside of the `AsyncTask` . You do not need the `AsyncTask`

Comment: yes you do not need to handle any background thread yourself. Everything is handled by Retrofit

Comment: Ok, so in case of a built-for class is it better to do this in the constructor or just in the Activity?

Comment: in the Activity